# ssis foreach loop error [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: "Excel Source" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA"

Tags: sql, excel, ssis

I have created an SSIS project to load data from Excel file source. I am using `foreach` loop to take all Excel files from a selected folder. The loop seems to take the first file, but when it takes the next file an error occurs. It says that it needs a new metadata. The Excel source have the same file format and the same header (only one column data).

I am looking for an advice.

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: Excel data types can change on the fly. For example if data in a column happens to be really wide the data type will change from character to long and you'll get this error. The _same_ file might even throw this error if data is in a different order. One solution is to import text files instead of CSV files.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes excel will actually have more columns than it appears.  Two ways to check this:
1. Save as csv and see if you have extra ,,, at the end of each line.
2. Create a quick test package and connect to the excel file and verify that the source has only one column.

Comment: i was try these two way check
1. there are no extra column in the file after save as csv.
2. its a bit strange, when i try to load data from each file. the data show perfectly, same data format, only one column, only the data are different.